# Line breaks not being recognized in SQL Server Import Wizard

Tags: python, sql-server, line-breaks, sql-import-wizard

I am using this Python program to append all of the files in my directory to one large fixed width text file (about 20 million records):

```
import glob

filenames = glob.glob("*.txt")
with open('wage.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
    for fname in filenames:
        with open(fname) as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

The SQL Server import wizard does not recognize any line breaks and each line extends out ~32,000 characters before wrapping around to the next line.

When I look at the file as a delimited file the line breaks are there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does `sql-server` complains about a specific error?

Comment: No. It does however show a back square that I believe is supposed to be the line break character

Comment: Could the fact that some lines are 58 characters long and others are 93 (extra field)? I'm wondering if this is causing a problem for structuring the data based on the first x number of rows

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know :(

Comment: Have you tried `ragged right` instead of fixed width? "Ragged right files are files in which every column has a fixed width, except for the last column, which is delimited by the row delimiter." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-flat-file-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard

Comment: @SqlZim This appears to have done the trick. Thank you. I was not aware of this. This makes sense as the last field either isn't present or if is of varying lengths in the file.

Comment: @Ben Moved my comment to the answer section. Hopefully this can help someone else as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment about the lines being different lengths:

Have you tried **ragged right** instead of **fixed width**?

> Ragged right files are files in which every column has a fixed width, except for the last column, which is delimited by the row delimiter. [docs - Connect to a Flat File Data Source (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-a-flat-file-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard)